# How to login to gmail through with curl?

Tags: php, curl

Hey,
    I was trying to login through command line using curl. 
    Following Error is displayed every time

```
     "Moved Temporarily"
```

I used the curl command

```
curl -u username:password http://mail.google.com/mail -v
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your curl command is being redirected. Use the following in order to continue pursuing the correct http link until you find a connection.

```
curl -u username:password http://mail.google.com/mail -v -L
```